# Could not cast value of type to UINavigationController swift3

Tags: ios, swift3, delegates, navigationcontroller

I'm getting the following cast error (when I click on the "+" button in the simulator [NavigationController]) and can't figure out why. 
I'm using Swift3. Thanks for your help!

*MainVC.swift*

```
        protocol AddTaskDelegate: class {
            func saveTask(by controller: AddVC, with data: [String:String])
        }


        class MainVC: UIViewController {
            //    all tasks from the database
            var tasks = [ToDoListTasks]()

            @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!

            //    connect with Core Data
            let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    ...

//    prepare segue to send data
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "AddSegue" {
            let navigationController = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
            let childViewController = navigationController.topViewController as! AddVC

            childViewController.delegate = self as! AddTaskDelegate
        }
    }
 }
```

*AddVC.swift*

```
class AddVC: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate: AddTaskDelegate?
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read the error message. You are saying

```
segue.destination as! UINavigationController
```

But the destination of this segue is *not* a UINavigationController.

Comment: Hey Matt, Thanks for your help.